# Notion between connected and strongly connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a directed graph without loops (or even better an oriented graph). Let us assume that $G$ is finite.
The graph $G$ is *connected* if its underlying graph $G^*$ is connected (i.e., for every pair of vertices $u$ and $v$ in $G^*$, there is a $u,v$-path in $G^*$). The graph $G$ is *strongly connected* if for every pair of vertices $u$ and $v$ in $G$, there is a directed $u,v$-path in $G$.

**Is there a notion between 'connected' and 'strongly connected'?**
For the specific purpose I had in mind for oriented graphs, every "intermediate" notion I came up with turned out be equivalent to strongly connectedness.

I would also be interested in an intermediate notion for mixed graphs $G$ (i.e. graphs where there are some arcs and some undirected edges), provided the new notion indeed reflect a connectivity property of $G$.

e.g.: One notion that is intermediate between connected and strongly connected is 'unilaterally connected'.
A directed graph $G$ is *unilaterally connected* if for any two vertices $u$ and $v$, there is a directed path from $u$ to $v$ or from $v$ to $u$ but not necessarily both.

Please post one notion per answer (mentioning generalisations in one answer is acceptable and appreciated).

Comment: What about counting the number of back-edges on u-v paths? Say that G is i-connected if between every pair of vertices there’s a path with at most i back edges?

Comment: @daniello Sorry, I don't understand what you meant by back edges. Are you assuming a DFS representation of the graph and talking about back edges in that DFS tree?

Comment: What I mean is allowing at most i edges to go in the wrong direction in the definition of a u-v path.

Comment: @daniello That's interesting. Please post it as an answer.